# HMMT Probability Question - Solution Verification

Tags: probability

Alice and Bob are playing in an eight-player single-elimination rock-paper-scissors tournament. In the
first round, all players are paired up randomly to play a match. Each round after that, the winners of
the previous round are paired up randomly. After three rounds, the last remaining player is considered
the champion. Ties are broken with a coin flip. Given that Alice always plays rock, Bob always plays
paper, and everyone else always plays scissors, what is the probability that Alice is crowned champion?
Note that rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock.

Solution:  Should we need to compute the probability that Alice and Bob don't meet in Round 1 and Round 2 and mulitply them such as this

$(1-\frac{1}{{8\choose2}})(1-\frac{1}{{4\choose2}}) = \frac{45}{56}$

Can someone verify the answer, please?

Comment: Maybe I have the rules wrong...isn't this determined by the first round?  If $A$ plays anyone but $B$ then $A$ will win because rock beats scissors.  $B$ will also be playing scissors and will therefore lose.  That will leave $A$ unopposed.  Of course, if $A$ faces $B$ in the first round, she will lose.  So, isn't the answer $\frac 68$?

Comment: You are right!. Did not think through the rules, A is unopposed

Comment: A can be anywhere, the probability that B meets A in the first round is 1/7, so A loses with Pr=1/7, else wins with Pr = 6/7

Comment: @trueblueanil is absolutely correct.  Of course, $A$ will not be matched against herself so there are only $7$ opponents to choose from, $6$ of whom are winners for $A$.